# Undefined index q

Tags: 7

I have 2 websites on the same server.
They both use the same modules.

In one of them, I get the following notices:

> Notice: Undefined index: q in current_path() (line 355 of /var/www/drupal/includes/path.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: q in l() (line 2424 of /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: q in arg() (line 2792 of /var/www/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Does anyone have any idea about what can cause these notices?
The website is working perfectly, and I know I can put some error_reporting in the settings.php, but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Sorry, drupal 7.21

Comment: Do you have any URL rewriting module or htaccess rules added ?

Comment: I have Boost (with htaccess rules. works perfect) and Redirect modules active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind,
That was a stupid mistake of mine in my custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Line 355 of /includes/path.inc contains this code:

```
return $_GET['q'];
```

So, we can suppose, that $_GET['q'] is undefined. According to documentation, this variable is initialized in [drupal_path_initialize](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7) function during bootstrap. It's code:

```
function drupal_path_initialize() {
  if (empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
  }
  $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
}
```

Maybe, the function [drupal_get_normal_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7) gives undefined value for 'site_frontpage' var?

Comment: I have changed drupal_path_initialize to include the following code at the end:
<?php
if(empty($_GET['q'])){
 watchdog('check','empty');
}
?>
But it's never empty in this function. it always contains good value.

Comment: do you still get this error: Undefined index: q in current_path() (line 355 ?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, that was a stupid mistake I made somewhere in the theme unset($_GET['q']) for some stupid reason. Thanks for the help!